# Why Isabelle prover can't recognize a defined class?

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

```
class semigroup=
  fixes mult::"'a⇒'a⇒'a" (infixl "⊗" 70)
  assumes assoc: "(x⊗y)⊗z=x⊗(y⊗z)"

theorem main_theorem:
  fixes K::"semigroup"
  shows "∀x,y,z∈K. (x⊗y)⊗z=x⊗(y⊗z)"
```

The code `fixes K::"semigroup"` prompted an error with "Undefined type name: semigroup".

Comment: Classes are sorts, not types. Hence you need `'a :: semigroup`. Your forall is also strange.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are sorts, i.e., *properties* on types, not type. This has two major advantages when using them. First a type can be in multiple classes. Second, two types can be in a single class. However, Isabelle does not allow you to have one type in the same class multiple times.

What does this mean for you:

```
class semigroup=
  fixes mult::"'a⇒'a⇒'a" (infixl "⊗" 70)
  assumes assoc: "(x⊗y)⊗z=x⊗(y⊗z)"

theorem main_theorem:
  fixes x y z ::"'a :: semigroup"
  shows "(x⊗y)⊗z=x⊗(y⊗z)"
```

Here is an example where you need two classes:

```
  fixes x y z ::"'a :: {semigroup, plus}"
  shows "(x⊗y)⊗z=x⊗(y+z)"
```

If you omit the sort plus, you will get the error message `Variable 'a::semigroup not of sort plus`.

It is more common in Isabelle to no write ∀ and instead rely on the generalization done automatically by lemma. The pure forall is also nicer to manipulate.